# JS - new image file saying images don't exist even though they do

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, image, object

Hey fellow programmers,

I'm having some problems with some file reading. I have a series of jpeg and png images in a folder named with UID's starting at 0 and I know they exist, but this code throwing an error that says

"Uncaught TypeError: image.exists is not a function"

And I've done reasearch and I'm pretty sure .exists() is a thing. Do browsers not support that function anymore? Any help to why would be great!

```
// Images are located "UploadedImages/(the UID).(the Image Type)" 
// myArr is an array of JSON objects 
// newUIDs is an array of UID's for images that exist
// biggestUID is just for some other functions

for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
    image = new File([myArr[i].UID], "UploadedImages/" + myArr[i].UID + "." + myArr[i].imageType); 
    if (image.exists()) {
        newUIDs.push(myArr[i].UID);
        if (myArr[i].UID > biggestUID) {
            biggestUID = myArr[i].UID; 
        } // if
    } else {
        console.log(image + "with UID " + myArr[i].UID + " doesn't exist"); 
    } // if/else
} // for
```

Comment: What are you expecting `.exists()` to test? That's not a method of `File`

Comment: @CertainPerformance To test if the image exists...I though it was a valid method for file. Well, thank you. Do you know of any valid methods that would do the same thing for images?

Comment: You should probably have a look at [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) because here all you do create are UTF-8 text files with `name` property set to `"UploadedImages/..."` File does no fetching at all.